# Argument of type (...) is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: typescript

I want to use the Array function `includes`. But the internal parameter "searchElement" has the typeof `never`. This makes no sense for me because I can make single `==` comparisons with code completion and no type - errors:

```
export default async function getValidationObjectForEnergyType(energyType: keyof IdentificatorToEnergytypeMapping): Promise<void> {
    const energyTypeIdentificators: IdentificatorToEnergytypeMapping = {
        Strom: [
            "contactInformationLabel",
            "contractNumberLabel",
            "emailLabel",
            "phoneLabelPower",
            "zipLabelPower"
        ],
        Gas: [
            "contactInformationLabelGas",
            "contractNumberLabelGas",
            "emailLabelGas",
            "phoneLabelGas",
            "zipLabelGas"
        ],
    };
    // this is okay
    energyTypeIdentificators[energyType][0] == "emailLabel";
    // but this is not ?!
    energyTypeIdentificators[energyType].includes("emailLabel")
}

// Types:
interface IdentificatorToEnergytypeMapping {
    Strom: MrInputKeysPower[];
    Gas: MrInputKeysGas[];
}

type MrInputKeysPower = keyof MrInputsPower;
type MrInputKeysGas = keyof MrInputsGas;

interface MrInputsPower {
    contactInformationLabel: string;
    contractNumberLabel: string;
    emailLabel: string;
    phoneLabelPower: string;
    zipLabelPower: string;
}

interface MrInputsGas {
    contactInformationLabelGas: string;
    contractNumberLabelGas: string;
    emailLabelGas: string;
    phoneLabelGas: string;
    zipLabelGas: string;
}
```

Typescript gives me the following error:

```
Argument of type '"emailLabel"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

Maybe im mistaken but it feels like a typescript - bug.

When I use `energyType: string` as parameter the part `energyTypeIdentificators[energyType].includes("emailLabel")` behaves like expected.

Answer (score 0):

After checking your code, I think, I know why this is happening. In essence

```
const energyTypeIdentificators: IdentificatorToEnergytypeMapping
```

has two arrays as attributes. the type of both is an array of interfaces also (`MrInputKeysPower` and `MrInputKeysGas` respectively)  and they aren't string.

So, when you are passing a `string` to search using `includes` are always `'never'` because of that, because you are trying to compare a `string` with a specific interface (`MrInputKeysPower` or `MrInputKeysGas`), which is never a `string`. The comparison `==` is only performed as true with the name of any attribute in the interface, if it is not a name, this error will be happen:

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"contactInformationLabel" | "contractNumberLabel" | "emailLabel" | "phoneLabelPower" | "zipLabelPower" | "contactInformationLabelGas" | "contractNumberLabelGas" | "emailLabelGas" | "phoneLabelGas" | "zipLabelGas"' and '"foo"' have no overlap.

Due this, you should check for email in that way:

```ts
if(energyTypeIdentificators[energyType]["emailLabel"]){

}
```

or

```ts
if(energyTypeIdentificators[energyType].emailLabel){

}
```

even you can check using `undefined`:

```ts
energyTypeIdentificators[energyType]["emailLabel"] === undefined
```

Comment: Then why can i not use `energyTypeIdentificators[energyType][0] == "foo";` Typescript is giving me an error. So `The comparission == is always performed` is not correct, right?

Comment: yes, you are right, my mistake. I update the answer

Comment: Thanks. But i don't understand that part: `and they aren't string` the properties of the interfaces are strings. That's why I can use the comparison with `==`. And `includes` is searching for an element in the array that contains only strings. I still don't understand why I can't use `includes` that way

Comment: Extracting directly from *lib.es2016.array.include.d.ts* -> ```includes(searchElement: T, fromIndex?: number): boolean;``` T is ```MrInputKeysPower``` or ```MrInputsGas``` not an string in your case, this is the awesome part to use generics. You are trying to use ```includes``` mixing types. You are not checking if ```"emailLabel"``` exists in your interface, you are checking if an string ```"emailLabel"``` is IN the array